# SwiftUI List with selector: selecting does not work for custom type (macOS)

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here; basically I fail to get a selection in a list of a custom type in my macOS app. Is there a conformance I am missing?

`List1` represents a list of my custom type, in which I cannot select an entry, whereas in `List2`, where I am just using Int, it works.

[image]

These are my views:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ListView1()
            Divider()
            ListView2()
        }
    }
}

struct ListView1: View {
    @State private var selection: Item? = nil
    
    var localSyslogEntries = [
        Item(message: "message 1"),
        Item(message: "message 2"),
        Item(message: "message 3"),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(localSyslogEntries, selection: $selection) { entry in
            VStack {
                Text(entry.id.uuidString)
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 200.0)
    }
}

struct ListView2: View {
    @State private var selection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        List(0..<10, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { index in
            VStack {
                Text("Index \(index)")
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 200.0)
    }
}
```

And here's the custom type:

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID
    let message: String
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), message: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add id

```
List(localSyslogEntries, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { entry in
```

Comment: Confirmed working, thanks. Why is this though? I am conforming to `Identifiable`, shouldn't that suffice?

Comment: Since you have added id in the list but how list know that? how it can be identified? that's why need to use the id in the list.

Comment: Well, so far I was under the impression that conforming to `Identifiable` (i.e. having a unique `id` for sure) is sufficient to show list rows–which it is. So there must be a reason why it is not when it comes to list  *selection* (also I do realise that I have to use `id: \.self` rather than `id: \.id` which I would have had to do when it comes to row content. So I don't fully get it, I have to admit – but then again: it does definitely work, so I am sure there's an easy explanation that I just don't understand yet, I guess...

Comment: The explicit `id` is needed, Xcode 13

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I think the reason this is needed is because the selection binding is for the list item’s *ID* rather than for the item itself. If we want the item itself to be passed to the selection binding, we need to manually specify that we want to use the item itself as the ID. Very confusing… I don’t know why there are no generic type constraints to prevent us at compile time from using the wrong type for the selection variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this very same thing, and this question helped me solve it; but I think I have something to add to it.

(For context, I'm using XCode 14.2 on Monterey)

My struct was defined as follows:

```swift
enum ItemType: String {
    case URI, UTI
}

internal protocol ItemProtocol: Hashable, Identifiable where ID == String {
    var contentType: ItemType { get set } // this is an enum
    var contentName: String { get set }
    var contentDescription: String { get set }
//  var displayName: String { get set }
    var id: String { get }
}

struct ItemStruct: ItemProtocol {
    var contentType: ItemType

    var contentDescription: String = ""

//  var displayName: String

    var fileExtensions: String = ""
    var contentName: String = ""

    var id: String {
        contentName
    }

    init (type: ItemType, _ contentName: String, _ contentDescription: String? = nil) {
        self.contentType = type
        self.contentName = contentName
        if let description = contentDescription {
            self.contentDescription = description
        }
        else {
            switch type {
            case .URI:
                self.contentDescription = maybeGetURIDescription(contentName) ?? ""
            case .UTI:
                self.contentDescription = UTType(self.contentName)?.description ?? ""
            default:
                self.contentDescription = ""
            }
        }
        switch type {
            case .UTI:
            self.fileExtensions = copyStringArrayAsString(LSWrappers.UTType.copyExtensionsFor(self.contentName), separator:", ") ?? "" // This method produces a delimited string from a [String] input.
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

And my view was:

```swift
enum ContentTabs: String {
    case Internet, URIs, UTIs
}

let internetDescriptions = ["http":"Web Browser",
                      "mailto":"E-Mail",
                      "news":"News",
                      "rss":"RSS",
                      "ftp":"FTP",
                      "im":"Instant Messaging"] // In practice, these are just shortcuts for the most commonly-used URI Schemes.

func makeInternetContent() -> [ItemStruct] {
    var array = [ItemStruct]()
    for (name, description) in internetDescriptions {
        array.append(ItemStruct(type:.URI, name, description))
    }
    return array
} // This is just a temporary method to provide basically static data while I learn how SwiftUI works.

struct ContentTab<Item>: View where Item: ItemProtocol {
    @State private var searchFilter: String = "Search test"
    @State private var selection: String?
    @State private var selection2: String?
    @FocusState private var searchFocused: Bool

    var activeTab: ContentTabs = ContentTabs.Internet
    private var contentRows: [Item] = [Item]()
    init (activeTab: ContentTabs, content: [Item]) {
        self.activeTab = activeTab
        self.contentRows = content
    }
    func displayName(_ item : Item) -> String {
        switch activeTab {
        case .Internet: return item.contentDescription
        default: return item.contentName
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            VStack() {
                //              TextField("Search...", text: $searchFilter)
                //                  .focused($searchFocused)
                List(contentRows, id:\.self, selection: $selection) { item in
                    Text("\(displayName(item)), id: \(item.id), hashValue: \(item.hashValue)")
                }.listStyle(BorderedListStyle())
                    .searchable(text: $searchFilter, placement: SearchFieldPlacement.automatic)
                List(["One", "Two", "Three"], id:\.self, selection: $selection2) {
                    Text($0)
                }
                Text("Selected: \(self.selection ?? "")")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I had the exact same problem as you did. Second list worked, first didn't.

If I removed the `id:\.self` from the second list, I got an compiler error because String does not conform to Identifiable.

That got me thinking and I tried removing that argument and now both lists work as expected.

It seems that `id:\.self` is only really needed if your items don't conform to Identifiable.